# Convert.ToInt32() a string with Commas

Tags: c#

I have a string that sometimes has commas seperating the number like `1,500` and I need to convert this to an Int, currently it is throwing an exception, can someone tell me how to fix this so that sometimes I may input numbers with commas and other times with out commas and it will still convert.

Comment: Remove commas before conversion.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to convert this to two ints?  Use String.Split().

Comment: i have the same problem @big-z. i have removed commas:  bool totalPriceConversionResult = decimal.TryParse(txtTotalPrice.Text.Replace(",",""), out totalPrice) and convert it to: TotalPrice = totalPriceConversionResult ? Convert.ToInt32(totalPrice) : 0. but it gives me a 0 vaue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359906

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You could use [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) and add the [`NumberStyles.AllowThousands`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) flag:

```
int num = int.Parse(toParse, NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

Or [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) letting you know if the operation succeeded:

```
int num;
if (int.TryParse(toParse, NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out num))
{
    // parse successful, use 'num'
}
```

Comment: You're kidding, .Net can do that?!  Nice!

Comment: Very nice, use NumberStyles.Number flag if you want to parse greater numbers like billions.

Comment: Bit old but in case some one runs across this. Best to use a combo flag here like NumberStyles.Number, or NumberStyles.Float, as it combines in the AllowThousands, as well as AllowTrailingSign and AllowDecimalPoint, which will break Double.Parse and Double.TryParse if you dont have them

Comment: Why does `int.Parse("1,23,4", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);` parse successfully?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Decimal.Parse()` then cast the result to `int`. This works with the current culture as well, or you can specify a `CultureInfo` to use. No need to manually handle commas, decimal points, etc, that's all built in to .NET.

Answer (score 4):

What's with the brute force suggestions of removing commas?? What if the string is something like "1,1,1"? Is this a valid number? Removing commas would make it a valid number and make the conversion semantically incorrect.

There's a reason NumberStyles exist and the Int.Parse() method can parse with or without regard to the number style.

Comment: `int.Parse("1,1,1", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);` returns `111`, so .NET does indeed think it is a valid number.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have to worry about rules for various countries (eg. some use comma as decimal position instead of thousands separator), then just strip out the commas first.

e.g

```
string nastyNumber = "1,234";
int result = int.Parse(nastyNumber.Replace(",", ""));
```

(replace int with double if you need floating point)

Answer (score 2):

You can do `replace(';', '')` before you convert it to int.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was so simple in C# ... thought I had to do RegEx to replace them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code

```
int num = Strings.Replace(str, ",", string.Empty);
```

This replaces all occurrences of "," with "" (empty string). So 1,000,000 turns 1000000

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the commas with `String.Empty` prior to calling `Convert.ToInt32()`, or you can look into using `Int32.Parse()` or `Int32.TryParse()` with `NumberStyles.AllowThousands` as one of the parameters.

[Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx)

[Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)