# convert string number to integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert.ToInt32() a string with Commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824326/convert-toint32-a-string-with-commas)

i have a value in the label as: 12,000

and i wish to convert it into an integer like 12000 (use it for comparison)

i tried int k = convert.toint32("12,000"); this does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string k = "12,000";
 int i = Convert.ToInt32(k.Replace(",", ""));
```

will work

Comment: This code is spectacularly culture-insensitive, and will fail when the application is run in a locale (and provided with a string) that uses `.` as the thousands' separator.

Answer (score 1):

You're being screwed up by the comma. If all of your values have commas in them, you'll want to run a string.replace() to remove them. Once that comma is gone, it should work fine.

A more thorough way would be to Parse it, allowing for thousands.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
var number = Int32.Parse("12,000", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

string num = "12,000";
 int k = Convert.ToInt32(num.Replace(",",""));