# Percentage Regex with comma

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations

I have this RegEx for C# ASP.NET MVC3 Model validation:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]*\,?[0-9]?[0-9]")]
```

This works for almost all cases, except if the number is bigger than 100.
Any number greater than 100 should show error.
I already tried use [Range], but it doesn't work with commas.

> Valid: 0 / 0,0 / 0,00 - 100 / 100,0 / 100,00.
>
> Invalid (Number > 100).

Comment: How are you receiving this value?  Why wouldnt `int.TryParse()` work?

Comment: Further to @paqogomez' suggestion, you can see it in action here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824326/convert-toint32-a-string-with-commas

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if zero's are only optional digits at the end but

```
 #  (?:100(?:,0{1,2})?|[0-9]{1,2}(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?)

 (?:
      100 
      (?: , 0{1,2} )?
   |  
      [0-9]{1,2} 
      (?: , [0-9]{1,2} )?
 )
```

Zero's only option at end

```
 #  (?:100|[0-9]{1,2})(?:,0{1,2})?

 (?:
      100 
   |  [0-9]{1,2} 
 )
 (?: , 0{1,2} )?
```

And, the permutations for no leading zero's except for zero itself

```
 # (?:100(?:,0{1,2})?|(?:0|[1-9][0-9]?)(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?) 

 (?:
      100 
      (?: , 0{1,2} )?
   |  
      (?:
           0
        |  
           [1-9] [0-9]? 
      )
      (?: , [0-9]{1,2} )?
 )


 # (?:100|0|[1-9][0-9])(?:,0{1,2})? 

 (?:
      100 
   |  
      0
   |  
      [1-9] [0-9] 
 )
 (?: , 0{1,2} )?
```

Comment: You need to include start and end of string controls, otherwise it will still match on larger numbers. Quick and dirty, "^(?:100|[0-9]{1,2})($|,0{1,2})$" works.

Comment: The OP didn't show ^$ anchors in the example. I won't either. And the quick & dirty regex obfuscates the anchors making it hard to read, while ^(?:100|[0-9]{1,2})(?:,0{1,2})?$ is ok because backtracking doesn't really have anywhere to go.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **RegEx** that matches your criteria:

```
^(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9]{1,2})(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?|(?:100)(?:,0{1,2})?)$
```

*(Given your use case, I have assumed that your character sequence appears by itself and is **not** embedded within other content. Please let me know if that is not the case.)*

And here's a **Perl** program that demonstrates that RegEx on a sample data set. (Also see [live demo](http://ideone.com/Cd20ch).)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    # A1 => An integer between 1 and 99, without leading zeros.
    #      (Although zero can appear by itself.)
    #
    # A2 => A optional fractional component that may contain no more
    #       than two digits.
    #
    # -OR-
    #
    # B1 => The integer 100.
    #
    # B2 => A optional fractional component following that may
    #       consist of one or two zeros only.
    #

    if (/^(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9]{1,2})(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?|(?:100)(?:,0{1,2})?)$/) {
    #           ^^^^^^^^A1^^^^^^    ^^^^^A2^^^^      ^B1    ^^^B2^^

        print "* [$_]\n";
    } else {
        print "  [$_]\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
0
01
11
99
100
101
0,0
0,00
01,00
0,000
99,00
99,99
100,0
100,00
100,000
100,01
100,99
101,00
```

**Expected Output**

```
* [0]
  [01]
* [11]
* [99]
* [100]
  [101]
* [0,0]
* [0,00]
  [01,00]
  [0,000]
* [99,00]
* [99,99]
* [100,0]
* [100,00]
  [100,000]
  [100,01]
  [100,99]
  [101,00]
```

Comment: One thing the OP states is `Valid: 0,00 - 100`. I can only assume > 100 would be `100.99` which your regex matches. Maybe you can provide for that with a slight modification - `^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100(?=(?:,0{1,2})?$))(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?$` , +1 Anyway

Comment: @sln - Right you are. And your regex works perfectly! However, I revised my regex somewhat differently so that the terminating `$` would appear only once. My approach: **A)** First check for one or two-digits and an optional fractional part, and then **B)** check for the number `100` and its optional fractional part (which may consist of one or two zeros only). I also included additional data samples. If you see any disadvantages with my revised regex vs. yours, please let me know.