# choosing different conversions in a c# application

Tags: c#

I have a c# application that convert lengths. The application works and gives correct results if a user enters a number separated by a dot (3.45) but if a user puts a comma instead (3,45) it gives wrong results. Does anyone know how i can counteract the problem

```
    private void butCal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // initialising and declaring variables 

        double miles, kilometres, feet, metres, inches, centimetres = 0;

        // the if statements initiates an event handler to select items from the conversions (combobox) to do conversion

        if (Conversions.Text == "Miles to Kilometres")
        {
            if (!double.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out miles)) // verifies that the string entered is a number
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number !"); // displays message if no number is entered
            }

            // Logic for doing calculations
            kilometres = miles * 1.6093; 
            txtAnswer.Text = kilometres.ToString("N2") + " Kilometres"; // displays the answer and rounds it off to two decimals

            txtAnswer.Visible = true;
            txtAnswer.Enabled = false;
            lblAnswer.Text = " Answer = ";
            lblAnswer.Visible = true;
        }

        else if (Conversions.Text == "Kilometres to Miles")
        {
            if (!double.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out kilometres))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.");
            }
            miles = kilometres * 0.621;
            txtAnswer.Text = miles.ToString("N2") + " miles ";

            txtAnswer.Visible = true;
            txtAnswer.Enabled = false;
            lblAnswer.Text = " Answer = ";
            lblAnswer.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (Conversions.Text == "Feet to Metres")
        {
            if (!double.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out feet))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.");
            }
            metres = feet * 0.3048;
            txtAnswer.Text = metres.ToString("N2") + " metres ";

            txtAnswer.Visible = true;
            txtAnswer.Enabled = false;
            lblAnswer.Text = " Answer = ";
            lblAnswer.Visible = true;
        }

        else if (Conversions.Text == "Metres to Feet")
        {
            if (!double.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out metres))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.");
            }
            feet = metres * 3.280839895;
            txtAnswer.Text = feet.ToString("N2") + " Ft ";

            txtAnswer.Visible = true;
            txtAnswer.Enabled = false;
            lblAnswer.Text = " Answer = ";
            lblAnswer.Visible = true;
        }

        else if (Conversions.Text == "Inches to Centimetres")
        {
            if (!double.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out inches))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.");
            }
            centimetres = inches * 2.54;
            txtAnswer.Text = centimetres.ToString("N2") + " cm ";
        }

        else if (Conversions.Text == "Centimeters to Inches")
        {
            if (!double.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out centimetres))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.");
            }
            inches = centimetres * 0.3937;
            txtAnswer.Text = inches.ToString("N2") + " Inches ";

            txtAnswer.Visible = true;
            txtAnswer.Enabled = false;
            lblAnswer.Text = " Answer = ";
            lblAnswer.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // resetting all labels, text fields and the conversion (combobox)
        Conversions.SelectedIndex = -1;
        txtNumber.Clear();
        txtAnswer.Clear();
        butCal.Visible = false;

        // Hidding text fields and labels until they are called
        txtAnswer.Visible = false;
        txtNumber.Visible = false;
        lblAnswer.Visible = false;
        lblNumber.Visible = false;
    }

    private void butExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close(); // exits the application
    }
```

Comment: cant u just replace `,` with `.` at the beginning. Please elaborate **WRONG RESULT**

Comment: @NitinVarpe - no, because `3,100` *does not* mean `3.100`, it means `3100` (or other way around depending where you happen to live)....

Answer (score 1):

double.TryParse has an overload taking a Culture or number styles.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx

Specifically for `IFormatProvider provider` parameter you may use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture for the dot

Answer (score 1):

if you are specifically talking about (3,45) its ok to throw an error because 3,45 probably means nothing. and still if you want it to work then use solution by @selman22 else if you are confirm that the input entered by the user will be one of the standards ie that the , will be used to seperate thousands then use the solution given here  [Convert.ToInt32() a string with Commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824326/convert-toint32-a-string-with-commas) which is similar for double or the solution given by @Softlion

Comment: The problem here is that `3,45` is still considered a valid number. Depending on the user's regional settings, it will be (mis)interpreted as either `3.45` or `345`. So when do you throw the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = txtNumber.Text;
if(text.IndexOf(',') > 0)
{
   text = text.Replace(',','.');
}
```

Comment: What if something like this is entered `1,23.3` :)? Why even bother - answer to everything is 42 so `text = "42"` guarantees correct parsing and reliable result.

Comment: it's a special case :D then we need to make some extra validation,but OP didn't ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering ur requirement. You can try below method

```
   try
{
    double.Parse(txtNumber.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
}
catch(Exception ae)
 {
            MessageBox.Show("Not a Number")
 }
```