# Regular expression to check for part of a string and extract a number with commas

Tags: c#, regex

I've been searching, and trying to figure out how to write a regular expression to solve my problem. So far I've come up short. This is what I'm trying to do. Find the part of a string that contains "Offset: " and extract the number after it. My issue is that the number can be from 1 to 10,000,000. Its the comma's that have me stumped. Any help is welcome. 
This is a sample of what it might look like. It's for c# just in case, as I read there can be different flavors of regex. Here is a sample of text.

```
"22:22:33.4643071","taskhostw.exe","4504","WriteFile","C:\Users\M O Shea\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\V01.log","SUCCESS","Offset: 286,720, Length: 4,096, I/O Flags: Write Through, Priority: Normal"

abdc Offset: 1 some more text
abdc Offset: 10 some more text
abdc Offset: 100 some more text
abdc Offset: 1,000 some more text
abdc Offset: 10,000 some more text
abdc Offset: 100,000 some more text
abdc Offset: 1,000,000 some more text
```

Comment: `var numberWithComma = someString.Replace("Offset: ", "");`  No need for regex at all

Comment: Will this work if the Offset part is in the middle of a long string. There is also more text after the number

Comment: You should include an actual example of your input so we can give you accurate answers.  I suspect Regex will be total overkill for your needs

Comment: So there will only ever be alpha characters in the string?  No special characters besides the `:` and `,`?  No other numbers?

Comment: I see your latest edit, will every input line be in the same order?  Meaning `Offset` will always appear last?

Comment: In a comma separated file yes, I had to split the file by " " in my method because of all the commas nested in the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
offset:\s*(?<offset>\d+(,\d+)*)
```

The `match.Groups["offset"].Value` should give you your number.

Comment: @maccettura yeah, but it satisfies the conditions.

Comment: It doesn't give you the _number_, it gives you the matching _string_. You still need to parse that string to get a number, and that's slightly complicated by the commas, [but see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824326/convert-toint32-a-string-with-commas).

Comment: Thats perfect thank. Yes im converting it to a number later. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading you correctly, this works

`Offset:[ ]+(10{0,2}(?:,0{3})?|10?(?:,0{3}){2})(?![,\d])`

https://regex101.com/r/yyhW7K/1

Readable version

```
 Offset: [ ]+     
 (                             # (1 start)
      1 
      0{0,2}
      (?: ,0{3} )?
   |  10?
      (?: ,0{3} ){2}
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?! [,\d] )
```