# Regex - Get digits after a colon

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex:

```
var topPayMatch = Regex.Match(result, @"(?<=Top Pay)(\D*)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

And I have to convert this to int which I did

```
topPayMatch = Convert.ToInt32(topPayMatchString.Groups[2].Value);
```

So now...

Top Pay: 1,000,000 then it currently grabs the first digit, which is 1. I want all 1000000.
If Top Pay: 888,888 then I want all 888888.
What should I add to my regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something as simple like `@"(?<=Top Pay: )([0-9,]+)"`. Note that, decimals will be ignored with this regex.

This will match all numbers with their commas after `Top Pay:`, which after you can parse it to an integer.

Example:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=Top Pay: )([0-9,]+)");
string str = "Top Pay: 1,000,000";

Match match = rgx.Match(str);
if (match.Success)
{
    string val = match.Value;
    int num = int.Parse(val, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}

Console.WriteLine("Ended");
```

Source:

- [Convert int from string with commas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1824349/1627271)

Comment: I get a Input string format incorrect error. Because it still has a comma. Did you try your code? I do not need decimals. It should be just an int type.

Comment: I did try the code. Can you post the full string you have?

Comment: @Davis I tried it, it works fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wFH2Hk

Comment: @Davis ps; check your number is valid (if it starts with a comma for example, you'll get an "Input string was not"..); somewhere, somehow, you're putting garbage in, so you're getting garbage out. You can cater for the "leading comma" case, for example, by adjusting the regex to `(\d[0-9,]*)`

Comment: @CaiusJard You're right - edited! And thanks for verifying it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the lookbehind, you don't need the capture groups and you can move the `\D*` into the lookbehind.

To get the values, you can match 1+ digits followed by optional repetitions of `,` and 1+ digits.

**Note** that your example data contains comma's and no dots, and using `?` as a quantifier means 0 or 1 time.

```
(?<=Top Pay\D*)\d+(?:,\d+)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=Top Pay\D*)` Positive lookbehind, assert what is to the left is `Top Pay` and optional non digits
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d+)*` Optionally repeat a `,` and 1+ digits

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dTop+Pay%5cD*%29%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%2c%5cd%2b%29*&i=Top+Pay%3a+1%2c000%2c000%0d%0aTop+Pay%3a+888%2c888&o=i) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/MLRHKY)

```
string pattern = @"(?<=Top Pay\D*)\d+(?:,\d+)*";
string input = @"Top Pay: 1,000,000
Top Pay: 888,888";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
{
    var topPayMatch = int.Parse(m.Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
    Console.WriteLine(topPayMatch);
}
```

Output

```
1000000
888888
```